# PHP structure changed into a jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

As this structure changed into a jQuery? And if this is possible at all?

```
$path=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$pathkor = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);

$var = "/актеры/женщины/";


if(strstr($pathkor, '%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B') or strstr($pathkor, '98+99+100+101')){
    print '<div class="punkt active"><a alt="А-Б-В-Г" title="А-Б-В-Г" href="'.$var.'98+99+100+101">А-Г </a> </div>';
} else {
          print '<div class="punkt "><a alt="А-Б-В-Г" title="А-Б-В-Г" href="'.$var.'98+99+100+101">А-Г </a> </div>';   
}
```

The meaning of this code. Find the latest entries in an alias, and compare them. And if there is a match then appoint a special class.

Comment: What do you mean by 'into *a* jQuery'?

Comment: Do you mean "code", not "structure"? Are you trying to convert this PHP code into Javascript code (supported by the jQuery library)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be more specific on how you want to identify the divs to add the classes to.

I imagine it would look something similar to:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var pathkor = path.split('/');
pathkor = pathkor[pathkor.length - 1];

var hrefvar = "/актеры/женщины/";

if(pathkor.match('%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B') != null || pathkor.match('98+99+100+101'))
{
    //$(FOO_SELECTOR).attr('href', hrefvar + '98+99+100+101');
    //$(FOO_SELECTOR).addClass('active');
}
else
{
    //$(FOO_SELECTOR).attr('href', hrefvar + '98+99+100+101');
}
```